# Issue with Kafka Connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have been utilizing Kafka Connectors to facilitate data transfer between databases. However, we have encountered an issue with the new connectors where only partial data is being transferred. The problem persists until we manually restart the connectors, after which all the data is successfully transferred. But it is not transferring data automatically, we have to restart the connectors everytime. Could you please provide any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this behavior? We also checked the properties file, tried increasing batch/fetch size but nothing seems working.

We have attempted to address this problem by deploying the connectors separately to ensure that resource constraints are not causing the issue. Despite these efforts, we are still facing the same problem. We also checked the properties file, tried increasing batch/fetch size but nothing seems working.